# Numerical Optimization with analytically unsolvable constraints

Tags: numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization

,Im working alreade quite long on a constrained numerical optimization problem.
I want to numerically maximize a function lets call it

```
f[xx_?(VectorQ[#,NumericQ]&)]:=x[1]+x[2]+x[3]
```

subject to an definite Integral of this function, lets call it

```
c1=NIntegrate[Abs[g[xx,y] -h[zz,y]],{y,0,1}]
```

`Integrate[Abs[g[x,y] -h[x,y],{y,0,1}]` is analytically not solvable, for specific values of `x[i]`, I'm getting numerical values for `c1`.
Now I want to maximize:

```
NMaximize[{f[x],c1<=1},xx]
```

I have to find a way how `NMaximize` passes the points it uses to the constraint `c1`. How can I tackle such a problem?

Edit: the functions `g[y_]` and  `h[y_]`, with `y[i]` fixed, `h` fixed, `z[i]` fixed, `n` is the dimension of `xx`, are given as:

```
g[y_?NumericQ,xx_?(VectorQ[#,NumericQ]&)]:=(1/(n*h))*Sum[x[i]*k[(y -y[i])/h],{i, 1, n}];
h[y_?NumericQ]:=(1/(n*h))*Sum[z[i]*k[(y -y[i])/h],{i, 1, n}];
k[u_] := Piecewise[{{1 - Abs[u], Abs[u] < 1},{0, True}}]
```

Comment: You will have to provide explicit expressions of the functions involved. Otherwise the answer probably will lie with switching to `NIntegrate` and adding `?NumericQ` to your definitions, but I doubt that anyone could be much more specific than that.

Comment: Ive added i have switched my definitions to  `g[y_?NumericQ,xx_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)]:=...`, and used `NIntegrate` unfortunately it didnt helped and just shows the errors, NIntegrate::inumr and NMinimize::bcons

Comment: @DanielRehsmann What actually do you try to optimise? Could you specify all parameters involved in you code?  Code also depends on version you run on. There is a typo in your code in definition of function `h[]` and parameter `h` have the same name.